# class function doesn't keep the variable's value

Tags: c++, function, class

I tried to implement a class (bign) in c++. In this class, a string is used to keep the value of the number. The problem is, when I assign a value("01234567") to the bign object a, the value is actually not saved. When run in DevCpp 5.6.1, the string, num, is not print on the screen. Why does this happen and how to fix it? Thank you.

```c++
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
class bign {
    public:
       int len;
       string num;

       bign() {
            len = 0;
       }

       bign operator= (string s) {
            len = s.size();
            for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                num[i] = s[i];
                cout << num[i]; //It works well.
            }
            cout<< "num" << num << endl; //Here num disappears.
            return *this;
        }

};
int main() {
    bign a;
    a = "01234567";
    cout << a.len << " " << a.num << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**
This program should reverse the number sequence to make it possible for precise numerical calculation, so it should be done in this way (but not using string copy). Also, the copy constructor and other elements will be added into the program later. The revised program is as following. The operator= function still has index out of bound error.

```c++
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
class bign {
    public:
       int len;
       string num;

       bign() {
            len = 0;
       }

       bign& operator= (string s) {
            len = s.size();
            num.reserve(len);
            for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                num[i] = s[len - i - 1];
                cout << num[i]; 
            }
            cout<< "num" << num << endl; //Here num disappears.
            return *this;
        }           
};
int main() {
    bign a;
    a = "01234567";
    cout << a.len << " " << a.num << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It does not "work well". You're accessing an out-of-bounds index in the `num` string in the loop.  Therefore the code produces undefined behavior.  Quit writing assignment operators and copy constructors when there is no need to -- the `len` and `num` will be copied correctly and safely without you creating your own function.

Comment: Think about the size of `num`? Did you ever allocate memory for `num`? Also, you do not need to loop in `operator=()`. Use the `std::string` [`operator=()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) and just write `num = s`. This will allocate enough memory for `num` to hold the contents of `s` and also copy them into `num`. (Edit: There are many other problems here as @RemyLebeau said in their answer).

Comment: That's what happens when you trifle with undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the function of std::string like this:

> num.push_back(s[i]);

instead of:

> num[i] = s[i];

Answer (score 4):

You are making several mistakes:

1. `operator=()` does not allocate, or otherwise ensure, that `num` is large enough for you to write characters to it via its `[]` operator.
2. `operator=()` needs to return a `bign&` reference.  Otherwise, it is returning a **copy** of `this`.
3. you have not implemented a copy constructor (see the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))).

Try this instead:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

class bign {
public:
    int len;
    string num;

    bign()
        : len(0)
    {
        cout << "(bign) len=0 num=''" << endl;
    }

    bign(const string &src) {
        : len(src.size()), num(src)
    {
        cout << "(bign) len=" << len << " num='" << num << "'" << endl;
    }

    bign(const bign &src)
        : len(src.len), num(src.num)
    {
        cout << "(bign) len=" << len << " num='" << num << "'" << endl;
    }

    bign& operator= (const bign &rhs) {
        len = rhs.len;
        num = rhs.num;
        cout << "(bign) len=" << len << " num='" << num << "'" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    bign a;
    a = "01234567";
    cout << "(main) len=" << a.len << " num='" << a.num << "'" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```